# Side notes to text

Tags: entities, nodes

I am looking for a module or a way to implement the following. 
Consider you have a body field, when filling in a content type. I want to give the possibility for the user to add notes on the side. I need to show the notes on the lines the editor assigned them to.

I haven't really found something out of the box.

Comment: You mean , display default text in the body for the particular content type.

Comment: No, how can I add notes on the side of the main text.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understand your point, what do you mean notes

Comment: Notes -> small text elements.

Comment: Would the footnotes module do the job? https://drupal.org/project/footnotes

Comment: I think I will be able to adjust it a bit! Thanks :)